# How to tell if class has been instanced?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, appdomain

I have a class implementing an interface. Is there a way to tell if that class has been instantiated (via `AppDomain` maybe) and then get a reference to the object via the known interface?

I suppose this is related to dependency injection. Rather than having a library with registered objects, I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Why would you want to do it? It might be an XY problem

Comment: You're basically describing dependency injection (and perhaps the singleton pattern) so why can't you use a DI library?

Comment: `Is there a way to tell if that class has been instantiated` what would the use case be for this? If you want to see if an object has ever been instantiated, you'd need to modify that object's class to provide some type of private static bool (or counter) that gets flagged when an object is [constructed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e16464c8-1b72-4485-9891-94da63c4ec2e/is-it-possible-to-tell-if-a-class-has-been-instantiated?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: @DavidG: I'm not ready to commit to that. I.e. - I'm exploring options. So far, I've only one place that I would be implementing DI and including a DI library for one object will likely get me to rethink my approach.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it needs clarification and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Then I strongly recommend you change your approach, there's very little reason these days to not do DI.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG, you could do a simple constructor injection to solve this easily without much change.

Comment: Yep. I've voted to close with the duplicates that already tread the same ground. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a static variable in the class that gets set when the constructor is called.

> get a reference to the object via the known interface

This makes it sound like you only expect to have one instance of this class. If so, check out the [Singleton pattern](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton).

Comment: Actually, I'm using a Singleton ... I'm rethinking how I'm doing this.

Comment: I downvoted this because it wasnt obvious what the OP is asking about and this answer looked more as a guess. Now it seems that it is one of the options that the OP has hence the upvote